# Which python can access a pre-compiled version of Quantlib?

Tags: windows, installation, quantlib

I was wondering if anybody knows where such an information is readily available.
Installing an UN-compiled version of QuantLib on Windows is such a hassle that I would rather
modify my python version in order to pip install Quantlib.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the wheels available from PyPI at https://pypi.org/project/QuantLib/#files.  Look for the ones with a "win" in their name (e.g., `QuantLib-1.16.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`, where the `cp37` part stands for CPython 3.7 and the `amd64` part indicates 64-bit architecture).  As of now, there are wheels for 64-bit Python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7.

Comment: Thank You Luigi Since your paper 'QuantLib-Python installation on Windows' already helped me installing QuantLib on my 3.7.3 python.

Comment: But I have no clue as to How you could derive python versions from the wheels names. But considering your plain reference to pre-compiled available for 3.7 I think I will stay with my presently working installation as 3.8 seems to be mainly about the new walrus operator (for me at least.)

Comment: I've updated the answer a bit.  I'll build 3.8 wheels for the next version of QuantLib.